# R: How to separate string in a cell into several cells in a row?

Tags: r, strsplit

I have following data

```
Data <- data.frame(
X = ("123 234 345 456","222 333 444 555 666" )
)


Data
#        X    
# 123 234 345 456 
# 222 333 444 555 666
```

A String in one cell, and the length of string is not same in each row

I want the following result

```
>Result
#    X    Y    Z    A    B
#   123  234  345  456  
#   222  333  444  555  666
```

one word in one cell

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strsplit` is not required here. `read.table` should work fine. Try:

```
read.table(text = as.character(Data$X), header=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
```

You will have to rename the resulting variable names though.

Comment: Hello, read.table is work, but the empty cell is filled as NA, how can I change NA as 0?

Comment: Assuming the output is stored as `Result`, try `Result[is.na(Result)] <- 0`

Comment: There is another problem, if the first line is 14 column, and the whole table is fixed 14 column, and longer row will be wrapped. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Dryad, you're joking right? You've removed your acceptance of the answer because of how R displays wide tables on your screen? Look into `options` and try to figure it out.

Comment: I read all options but I don't know which one should be set. Please help me fix this problem, and I will accept your answer again. Thank you!

Comment: @Dryad how hard you read the page? `width: controls the maximum number of columns on a line used in printing vectors, matrices and arrays`

Comment: @SimonO101, how can I set the max number of columns in read.table options?